# What is the error in this code?The javascript code is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the background color of my div element onclick.But it's not working.

```
<html>

     <head>
         <title>Event handling5</title>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <style type="text/css">
         .styleClass{
             display: table-cell;
             border: 5px solid black;
             padding: 20px;
             text-align: center;
         }
         </style>
         </head>
         <body>
             <div id="DIV1" class="styleClass">DIV1
            <div id="DIV2" class="styleClass">DIV2
                <div id="DIV3" class="styleClass">DIV3

                </div>
            </div>     
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var divElements=document.getElementsByTagName('div');
            for(var i=0;i<divElements;i++){
                divElements[i].onclick=function(){
                    this.style.borderColor='red';
                    alert(this.getAttribute("id")+"Border color changed");
                }
            }
            </script>
         </body>
 </html>
```

Only css functions are working and javascript function is not working.

Comment: You aren't closing the `<div>` tags correctly.

Comment: "it's not working" is not an acceptable way of telling us what is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Your script is wrong .

`divElements` is an array so do this . Add length to the for loop

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var divElements=document.getElementsByTagName('div');
            for(var i=0;i<divElements.length;i++){
                divElements[i].onclick=function(){
                    this.style.borderColor='red';
                    alert(this.getAttribute("id")+"Border color changed");
                }
            }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use .length with divElements in for loop: Try this code now....

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Event handling5</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        .styleClass {
            display: table-cell;
            border: 5px solid black;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="DIV1" class="styleClass">DIV1
        <div id="DIV2" class="styleClass">DIV2
            <div id="DIV3" class="styleClass">DIV3

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var divElements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
        for (var i = 0; i < divElements.length; i++) {
            console.log('--' + divElements[i]);
            divElements[i].onclick = function () {
                this.style.borderColor = 'red';
                alert(this.getAttribute("id") + "Border color changed");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The border turns red, but the alert is once for div 1, twice for div 2, and three times for div 3.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your for-loop

```
for(var i=0; i<divElements; i++){
/* Some Code */
}
```

Her you try to say, do it as long as `i` is smaller `divElements`. Problem here is, `divElements` itself don't give you any numeric value (for length). It's just the array.

To get it work you have to get the array length (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp) So you need `divElements.length`

In you for loop it would look like this.

```
for(var i=0;i<divElements.length;i++){
/* Some Code */
}
```

Here you can try out a working example and play with it: https://jsfiddle.net/Hoargarth/fdcL14wy/1/

And here if you just wanna see it running:

```html
 <head>
     <title>Event handling5</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <style type="text/css">
     .styleClass{
         display: table-cell;
         border: 5px solid black;
         padding: 20px;
         text-align: center;
     }
     </style>
     </head>
     <body>
         <div id="DIV1" class="styleClass">DIV1
        <div id="DIV2" class="styleClass">DIV2
            <div id="DIV3" class="styleClass">DIV3

            </div>
        </div>     
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var divElements=document.getElementsByTagName('div');
        for(var i=0;i<divElements.length;i++){
            divElements[i].onclick=function(){
                this.style.borderColor='red';
                alert(this.getAttribute("id")+"Border color changed");
            }
        }
        </script>
     </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go until the `length` of the results is reached and move the `script` tag into `head`.

```
<html>

     <head>
         <title>Event handling5</title>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <style type="text/css">
         .styleClass{
             display: table-cell;
             border: 5px solid black;
             padding: 20px;
             text-align: center;
         }
         </style>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function load() {
                var divElements=document.getElementsByTagName('div');
                for(var i=0;i<divElements.length;i++){
                    divElements[i].onclick=function(){
                        this.style.borderColor='red';
                        alert(this.getAttribute("id")+"Border color changed");
                    }
                }
            }
            </script>
         </head>
         <body onload="load();">
             <div id="DIV1" class="styleClass">DIV1
            <div id="DIV2" class="styleClass">DIV2
                <div id="DIV3" class="styleClass">DIV3

                </div>
            </div>     
            </div>
         </body>
 </html>
```